# Lua File Handling

Tags: file, lua, io

I got this error recently:

```
lua: Lua Testing.lua:36: bad argument #1 to 'read' (invalid option)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'read'
        Lua Testing.lua:36: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

And I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
file = assert(io.open("test.txt", "r"), "no file.")
print(io.read(file))
io.close(file)
```

To explain a few things, I'm using assert to make sure the file is there and it is.
I'm pretty new to Lua. I've googled about this error and I came up with nothing that helped me fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the result of `io.open` incorrectly.

> After you open a file, you can read from it or write to it with the methods read/write. They are similar to the read/write functions, but you call them as methods on the file handle, using the colon syntax. For instance, to open a file and read it all, you can use a chunk like this:
>
> ```lua
>    local f = assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
>    local t = f:read("*all")
>    f:close()
> ```

–[Programming in Lua: 21.2 – The Complete I/O Model](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html)

---

Also you did not get a very good error message, my IDE gave me:

```
so_test2.lua:2: bad argument #1 to 'read' (string expected, got FILE*)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'io.read'
    so_test2.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

You can see in this error string, it tells us specifically that the function expected a `string` and it was provided a `FILE*`(a file handle)

---

*Programming in Lua* is a great resource while learning Lua.

Comment: This worked! One small issue though
```local filename = "test.txt"
local file = assert(io.open(filename, "a+"))
file:write("Test.\n")
local data = file:read("*all")
print(data)
file:close()```
```
When printing data, the output is "nil" and when I check the file manually, the entire source code of my program is there.

Comment: data is not `nil` or at least is not when i run it in my ide, data is not formatted properly and instead you get `Test.\n` followed by a bunch of nonsense. you need to either not include a mode at all or call `io.open` with `r` when you want to read. [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual - io.open](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.open)